# How to enable a virtualenv in a systemd service unit?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

I want to "activate" a virtualenv in a systemd service file.

I would like to avoid having a shell process between the systemd process and the python interpreter.

My current solution looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=fooservice
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=fooservice
WorkingDirectory={{ venv_home }}
ExecStart={{ venv_home }}/fooservice --serve-in-foreground
Restart=on-abort
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/fooservice.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/sysconfig/fooservice.env

```
PATH={{ venv_home }}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
PYTHONPATH={{ venv_home }}/...
VIRTUAL_ENV={{ venv_home }}
```

But I am having trouble. I get ImportErrors since some entries in `sys.path` are missing.

Comment: Can you please include the errors you are getting?

Comment: @PraveenYalagandula The traceback does not contain any useful information, since the ImportError Exception and all lines above it contain only custom code which does not matter here.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The virtualenv is "baked into the Python interpreter in the virtualenv". So for most cases this means you can launch `python` or [`console_scripts`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) directly in that virtualenv and don't need to activate the virtualenv first or manage `PATH` yourself.:

```
ExecStart={{ venv_home }}/bin/fooservice --serve-in-foreground
```

or

```
ExecStart={{ venv_home }}/bin/python {{ venv_home }}/fooservice.py --serve-in-foreground
```

and remove the `EnvironmentFile` entry.

To verify that it is indeed correct you can check `sys.path` by running

```
{{ venv_home }}/bin/python -m site
```

and comparing the output to

```
python -m site
```

Comment: Yes, sys.path is correct. Thank you. I checked the difference between os.environ. It seems that VIRTUAL_ENV is not set, if I use `{{ venv_home }}/bin/python`.  Can this make trouble?

Comment: I don't know for certain but I have never had issues with `VIRTUAL_ENV` not being set.

Comment: good point Nils. Btw, fooservice.py doesn't make sense to be inside venv_home directory, I suppose its a typo in the question.

Comment: Note the suggested print commands are not compatible with Python 3. If you are using at least python 2.4, you can alternatively just use: `python -m site` to get a nicely formatted output of the sys.path variable along with additional information.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about `python -m site`. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: This approach doesn't work when the python process you're starting expects the virtualenv to be activated. For example, consider `{{ venv_home }}/bin/python -m newrelic.admin run-program python -m myapp`. That will launch python in the venv, invoke New Relic, and then it will fail to launch the app because `python` is not in the path because the venv is not activated.

Comment: Have you tried `{{ venv_home }}/bin/python -m newrelic.admin run-program {{ venv_home }}/bin/python -m myapp`?

Comment: Also appears to fail with python3 when the (`python3 -mvenv` created) venv has third party modules not in the python3 stdlib? See here: https://gist.github.com/brainstorm/bff8b439072ffadbd95ae901c659a6b5

Comment: @brainstorm I cannot reproduce your issues on OSX: https://gist.github.com/nils-werner/d98aff2b865dac9375570340ce635844. Maybe it has to with pcgr

Comment: @NilsWerner I ended up solving it by spawning a shell, nothing else worked on Ubuntu 17.10: https://github.com/umccr/pcgr-deploy/blob/master/ansible/files/pcgr.service.j2#L9 ... please ignore the jinja2 templating for ansible, it expands correctly when deployed.

Comment: For those wondering if this is ninja2....no, the double curly-braces are just placeholders the OP invented: https://superuser.com/questions/1209919/what-do-double-curly-braces-mean-in-systemd-scripts

Comment: what exactly does --serve-in-foreground do?

Comment: That's a parameter of the Python server the OP invented.

Comment: When I use the `{{ venv_home }}` syntax, I get errors that it's not a path.

Comment: If you look at syslog, then will realize this is not such a good idea, since filter by process name will become an issue b/c they all displayed as python. not the script name. instead.

Comment: That's a Python problem, and not specific to virtualenvs, no?

Answer (score 34):

While the path for libraries is indeed baked into the python interpreter of the virtualenv, I've had issues with python tools that were using binaries installed in that virtualenv. For instance, my apache airflow service wouldn't work because it couldn't find the `gunicorn` binary. To work around this, here's my `ExecStart` instruction, with an `Environment` instruction (which sets an environment variable for the service alone).

```
ExecStart={{ virtualenv }}/bin/python {{ virtualenv }}/bin/airflow webserver
Environment="PATH={{ virtualenv }}/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

`ExecStart`explicitly uses the python interpreter of the virtualenv. I'm also adding a `PATH` variable, which adds the binary folder of the virtualenv before the system `PATH`. That way, I get the desired python libraries as well as binaries.

Note that I'm using ansible to build this service, ergo the curly braces of jinja2.

Comment: Literally came looking for how to set the environment in a service because airflow couldn't find gunicorn. Was NOT disappointed! Thank you! I'm up and running.

Comment: Exactly , I was in need of Airflow automation through Ansible .
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case I just tried to add environment variables required for Flask, for instance

```
[Service]
Environment="PATH=/xx/yy/zz/venv/bin"
Environment="FLASK_ENV=development"
Environment="APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

I was using virtualenv so `/xx/yy/zz/venv/bin` is the path of virtualenv folder.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using virtualenv but pyenv: here is it just to use the real .pyenv path in the shebang and make sure it is in the PATH

Ex: pyenv activate flask-prod for user mortenb which is running in prod

```
/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/flask-prod/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Then to my flask scripts starting in systemd *.service I add the following shebang:

```
#!/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/flask-prod/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the minor wrinkles when you're running a FlaskApp via Gunicorn in the venv with systemd.   Let's say I've created a venv called FlaskVenv at /home/someuser/z_Venv which I might typically source with `source /home/someuser/z_Venv/FlaskVenv/bin/activate`, and that my Flask app is at `/home/someuser/FlaskCode/some-ui`

So interactively, I might run that with:

`cd /home/someuser/FlaskCode/someui`

then

`source /home/someuser/z_Venv/FlaskVenv/bin/activate`

then

`gunicorn -k gevent -w 4 -b :5001 main:appAF`

To make this into a systemd service I create a service file at `/etc/systemd/system/someui.service` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some UI
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=someuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser/FlaskCode/some-ui
ExecStart=/home/someuser/z_Venv/FlaskVenv/bin/python -m gunicorn -k gevent -w 4 -b :5001 main:app
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start it interactively (to test) with
`sudo systemctl start someui`
and get status with
`sudo systemctl status someui`

If all is well, enable autostart with:
`sudo systemctl enable someui`

If anything weird is going on I can check systemctl logs with `journalctl -xe`

Answer (score -1):

```
ExecStart=cd /root/app/working-directory && poetry run python my_app.py
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).