# Running flask automatically after boot

Tags: flask

I'm trying to run flask when my raspberry pi turns on.
I created a service for my flask API, this is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description= Flask API
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/bucketlist/
ExecStart=flask run --host=0.0.0.0
Restart=Always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I try `sudo systemctl start flask` then `sudo systemctl status flask` I get this error.

```
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]: Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]: Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]:     __import__(module_name)
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]:   File "/home/pi/bucketlist/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]:     from flask_api import FlaskAPI
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi flask[4769]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_api'
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: flask_api.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 10 09:56:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: flask_api.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I type `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` manually it works fine, I don't know why the service gives this error.

More info:

I also tried `python /home/pi/bucketlist/run.py` instead of  `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` in ExecStart.

I have a virtual environment set-up in the bucketlist directory.

Python 2.7.16

Flask 1.1.4

Werkzeug 1.0.1

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I am using virtualenv

Comment: it seems like it's not activating when I run the service, any idea what I should add to the .service file to activate it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211115/how-to-enable-a-virtualenv-in-a-systemd-service-unit