# Trouble enabling virtualenv as a systemcd service

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm new to VPS and I want to run a Python script forever. I followed instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211115/how-to-enable-a-virtualenv-in-a-systemd-service-unit) but I'm missing something because it's not working

I made my `botWooService.service` file in  `/etc/systemd/system/`. This is what it contains

```
[Unit]
Description=botWoo
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=home/bots/botWoo/venv
ExecStart=home/bots/botWoo/venv/bin/python home/bots/botWoo/main.py --serve-in-foreground
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl start botWooService` I get:

```
Failed to start botWooService.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status botWooService.service' for details.
```

I am not sure if it's not working properly because I am using Environment Variables and there is a `.env` file in `home/bots/botWoo/` or if the issue is due to something else.

When I run `home/bots/botWoo/venv/bin/python -m site` this is the output

```
sys.path = [
'/',
'/usr/lib64/python36.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python3.6',
'/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/home/bots/botWoo/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
'/home/bots/botWoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

And when I run `python -m site` I get this:

```
sys.path = [
'/',
'/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

So I am not getting the same output and I really don't know what this means.
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: The error you posted here is very light on details. You need to dig a little deeper to find the actual problem. As the error says: "See system logs and 'systemctl status botWooService.service' for details." Look at the log to see what the full error message is. Hopefully you can figure out which argument is invalid.

Comment: As a suggestion to try, I think `home...` should be `/home...`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that actually helped, I just changed it and didn't get any error when executing 'systemctl start botWooService'. Now I just need to see if it's actually running.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yep. now it's running. omg Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. The only issue was the missing /

Comment: For your future reference, I suggest you learn more about paths. Specifically the difference between absolute and relative paths. And you can also familiarize yourself with the (somewhat) standard directory structure used in Linux.